# How to overload "get" in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I wish to use the clojure "get" keyword for my own function. How can I prevent clojure from using the "get" defined in the standard libraries?

Comment: Trying to override language keywords is a tremendously bad idea.

Comment: Yes I know its a bad idea, but "get" doesn't have any easy to remember synonyms. I think even find is taken

Comment: fetch / load / retrieve, there's plenty man. Even better, how about something like get-<thing your're retrieving>

Comment: Yes, true, but "get" is the most natural sounding. Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: Isn't the whole point of namespaces to allow the re-use of the "good" names? Granted confusing the reader of the code is very valid concern but why not use a clojure's aliasing capability with a short prefix for the custom namespace? my/get (with something more meaningful than my for the proper context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned this is not necessarily a good idea, but you can do it like this:

```
user=> (ns your.name.space
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [get]))
nil
your.name.space=> (defn get [] "something")
#'your.name.space/get
your.name.space=>
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend using get for anything but getting a value out of a collection, since that's what anyone reading your code would expect it to do.

If you don't want to do that, **Wodin**'s answer is what you want.

If you actually want to "overload" get as per your title, that is, make the standard get function work with your own collection type - just make sure your collection implements ILookup, Map, or IPersistentSet and you can provide your own get/valAt method.